# Error in Rendering UI using React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I am using basic react component that need to render in UI, but I am facing below issue when I am attempting to do that.

**Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 37: Unexpected token }
    at 
http://localhost:63342/Sublime_Kishore/Tools/components/Body.jsx:37:undefined
}
^**

Please find my jxs file below.

```
var Body=React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return(
            <div>
            <div className="header_div">
                <img src="images/newsradio.png" className="_logo" />
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-lg login-btn">
                        <i className="fa fa-facebook fa-1.5x fbtn" styles="font-weight: bold;"></i><span>Login</span>
                    </button>
            </div>
            <div className="container_div">
            <div className="headers">
            <div className="production">Production</div>
            <div className="preprod">Pre-Production</div>
            <div className="qa">QA</div>
            <div className="dev" styles="width: 17%;">Development</div>
            </div>
            <ul className="production_block_main">
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            <li className="hovicon effect-1 sub-a"><img src="images/QA_tool_b.png" styles="margin-right: 30px;" /><span styles="font-family:initial">Enterprise</span></li>
            </ul>
            <div>

        );
    }  //This line is showing as error in my browser
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `</div>` before `</ul>`, also close last `</div>`

```
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/21208/)